# Shorten string in python

Tags: python, json, string

I'm trying to parse a json file with python however some of the strings that are returned appear to be too long and are being cut off and creating problems when parsing. I'm trying to figure out a way to return the string with a limited number of characters in the string however I'm having some trouble figuring out the best way to do that.

Right now I'm trying to work with something like the below:

```
def clean_string(string_val):
    return '\"' + string.replace(string_val,'\"','\'\'')+'\"'
    return string.replace(string_val,'$','\$')
    return string_val[:150]
```

However this isn't working and the script is still returning the full string.

Any thoughts on changes to the above code so that it could take a string of, say, 500 words and cut it down to 150 characters?

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if it would be helpful for me to include more information on this.

Comment: What do you mean by ``some of the strings that are returned appear to be too long and are being cut off ``. If you have the Json then every field must be there.

Comment: One of the elements within the JSON file is a description category for a given items. Some of the descriptions are rather long and I've noticed that the parser breaks whenever it encounters a long description and cuts off at about 8060 characters. I figured a good way to fix this is to cut down the string in the first place and then try to parse it. Any thoughts? Is there some type of max limit on json parsing that cuts out around 8060 characters?

Comment: The parser should certainly not be breaking down on long strings. I just checked and it handles a string of 10000 chars just fine. Perhaps there are some invalid characters confusing it. Would it be acceptable to post the JSON on pastebin?

Comment: check if you are missing something. it works ok http://codepad.org/TJeIjwhu

Comment: Guys OP wants to parse JSON and he's failing, it doesn't help to say that you can shorten the input string with the encoded JSON or to shorten a string extracted from successfully parsed JSON.

Comment: Sure thing here is an example of the JSON and the results: http://pastebin.com/c5W0Ee3k . I think there could be a few invalid characters creating an issue here and perhaps that is the actual I'm running into. I've already tried to escape out of the $ and some of the quotes, but perhaps there is more I'm missing? I just updated my original questions to include the two other lines I'm using to remove the quotes and $. Thanks Alex

Comment: All the lines of the function body `return` ! You only want the last line to do that. And then you need to save the result of `replace` in a variable: the value of `s.replace(blah)` is a new string, it does not alter `s` (strings are *immutable*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple returns in your function, so only the first one is firing and its returning on the first line.  This should be close to what you want.

```
def clean_string(string_val):
    string_val = '\"' + string_val.replace('\"','\'\'') + '\"'
    string_val = string_val.replace('$','\$')
    return string_val[:150]
```